# Calculating multiple conversions through a combo box

Tags: c#

So, below is as far as I've gotten. It keeps telling me I am unable to use a mathematical operator on a decimal or double. Unfortunately, those are what I have to use. What I'm trying to do is convert measurements of lengths from imperial to metric. I've looked through many other questions referring to this and was able to figure out parts of the code and how to get it to let me do an "if" statement. But I just can't figure out the math part of it. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    string conversions;
    decimal meter, feet, centimeter, inches, miles, kilometers;


    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        calculateConversions();


    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cbConversion.SelectedText = "Miles to Kilometers";
        string[] Conversion = new string[] { "Miles to Kilometers",
            "Kilometers to Miles",
            "Feet to Meters",
            "Meters to Feet",
            "Inches to Centimeters",
            "Centermeters to Inches" };
        { }
        for (int i = 0; i < Conversion.Length; i++)
        {
            cbConversion.Items.Add(Convert.ToString(Conversion[i]));
        }
        miles = 0m;
        kilometers = 0m;
        feet = 0m;
        meter = 0m;
        inches = 0m;
        centimeter = 0m;



    }


         private void cbConversion_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        conversions = Convert.ToString(cbConversion.SelectedItem);

        IList<string> lstString = new List<string>();
        lstString.Add("Miles:");
        lstString.Add("Kilometers:");
        lstString.Add("Feet:");
        lstString.Add("Meters:");
        lstString.Add("Inches:");
        lstString.Add("Centimeters:");

        label2.Text = lstString[cbConversion.SelectedIndex];

        IList<string> lstStringTwo = new List<string>();
        lstStringTwo.Add("Kilometers:");
        lstStringTwo.Add("Miles:");
        lstStringTwo.Add("Meters:");
        lstStringTwo.Add("Feet:");
        lstStringTwo.Add("Centimeters:");
        lstStringTwo.Add("Inches:");
        label3.Text = lstStringTwo[cbConversion.SelectedIndex];

    }

private void calculateConversions()
    {
        decimal input = Convert.ToDecimal(txtInput.Text);
        decimal output = Convert.ToDecimal(txtOutput.Text);

        if (cbConversion.SelectedText == "Miles to Kilometers")
        {
            decimal miles = Convert.ToDecimal("");


        }
```

I've even looked through my book and can't figure it out (it's a homework assignment)
The GUI I have. It's selected through the combobox and the entered text is calculated into the conversion. Everything works but the math
[image]

Comment: What's the error and at which line?

Comment: You may want to back up a step: "SelectedText" is likely not what you think it is, and `""` will never convert to decimal.  You should also use `Decimal.TryParse` on user input to catch cases when they type `I Like Pie` in place of a numeral

Comment: Okay, I got it to let me do the math part of it. I can't figure out how to display it in txtOutput.Text

Comment: To take (almost) anything (say something named `theThing`) and convert it to a string, call `theThing.ToString()`

Comment: I tried that. how do I display the output (kilometers) textbox? the issue is the labels change depending on the choice in the combo box chosen I get a FormatExeception was unhandled error
decimal input = Convert.ToDecimal(txtInput.Text);
            decimal output = Convert.ToDecimal(txtOutput.Text);
            if (cbConversion.SelectedText == "Miles to Kilometers")
            {
                miles = Convert.ToDecimal("");
                kilometers = Convert.ToDecimal(miles * 1.6093m);
                kilometers = output;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added `cbConversion.SelectedIndex = 0;` in form1_load to select the first index of the combo box, then on `calculateConversions()` function in every condition i output in the textoutput.text.

Then the rest you can do else if and research for other formula for conversion.

And I used `cbConversion.SelectedItem.ToString()` so you can get item text from combobox to compare.

You can try this

```
string conversions;
    decimal meter, feet, centimeter, inches, miles, kilometers;

    private void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        calculateConversions();
    }

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();



    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cbConversion.SelectedText = "Miles to Kilometers";
        string[] Conversion = new string[] { "Miles to Kilometers",
        "Kilometers to Miles",
        "Feet to Meters",
        "Meters to Feet",
        "Inches to Centimeters",
        "Centermeters to Inches" };
        { }
        for (int i = 0; i < Conversion.Length; i++)
        {
            cbConversion.Items.Add(Convert.ToString(Conversion[i]));
        }
        miles = 0m;
        kilometers = 0m;
        feet = 0m;
        meter = 0m;
        inches = 0m;
        centimeter = 0m;
        cbConversion.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }

    private void cbConversion_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        conversions = Convert.ToString(cbConversion.SelectedItem);

        IList<string> lstString = new List<string>();
        lstString.Add("Miles:");
        lstString.Add("Kilometers:");
        lstString.Add("Feet:");
        lstString.Add("Meters:");
        lstString.Add("Inches:");
        lstString.Add("Centimeters:");

        label2.Text = lstString[cbConversion.SelectedIndex];

        IList<string> lstStringTwo = new List<string>();
        lstStringTwo.Add("Kilometers:");
        lstStringTwo.Add("Miles:");
        lstStringTwo.Add("Meters:");
        lstStringTwo.Add("Feet:");
        lstStringTwo.Add("Centimeters:");
        lstStringTwo.Add("Inches:");
        label3.Text = lstStringTwo[cbConversion.SelectedIndex];


    }
    private void calculateConversions()
    {
        decimal input = Convert.ToDecimal(txtInput.Text);
        decimal mileToKM = Convert.ToDecimal(1.609344);

        if (cbConversion.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Miles to Kilometers")
        {

            decimal miles = (input * mileToKM);
            txtOutput.Text = miles.ToString();
        }


    }
```

**OUTPUT**
[image]

Comment: This does help a little. It's just not displaying the text in the output box. It did help a bit though. Shortened my coding a bit.

Comment: @Amanda what else is your problem? so I can figure it out and to help you.

Comment: The text isn't showing in the textbox. Nothing shows when I click calculate.

Comment: Nevermind, What I tried didn't work. If you enter something into the input text (miles on gui) it's supposed to show the conversion in the output textbox (kilometers) and it's not displaying the conversion

Comment: Just pass the value to textOutput.text, something like this txtOutput.Text = miles.ToString(); inside the conditions. I attached my output window so can check.

Comment: I copied exactly what you have. It's just not working. I have txtOutput.Text = miles.ToString(); and still nothing. I added my code as an answer

Comment: I couldn't get it to work even though I fixed it up like you showed me but I just copied and it works. I'll look at the differences in more detail and see what I missed before. Thank you for your help. Also, runs with no issues but it gives me a cs0414 error saying values were assigned but not used and they are used. So, I'm not sure.

Comment: @Amanda I get your error because you declared a variable doesn't been used.

These variables are not used: 
 decimal meter, feet, centimeter, inches, miles, kilometers;

Answer (score 0):

@justinmontalban this is the code I'm using now

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cbConversion.SelectedText = "Miles to Kilometers";
        string[] Conversion = new string[] { "Miles to Kilometers",
            "Kilometers to Miles",
            "Feet to Meters",
            "Meters to Feet",
            "Inches to Centimeters",
            "Centermeters to Inches" };
        { }
        for (int i = 0; i < Conversion.Length; i++)
        {
            cbConversion.Items.Add(Convert.ToString(Conversion[i]));
        }
        miles = 0m;
        kilometers = 0m;
        feet = 0m;
        meter = 0m;
        inches = 0m;
        centimeter = 0m;
        cbConversion.SelectedIndex = 0;



    }


         private void cbConversion_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        conversions = Convert.ToString(cbConversion.SelectedItem);

        IList<string> lstString = new List<string>();
        lstString.Add("Miles:");
        lstString.Add("Kilometers:");
        lstString.Add("Feet:");
        lstString.Add("Meters:");
        lstString.Add("Inches:");
        lstString.Add("Centimeters:");

        label2.Text = lstString[cbConversion.SelectedIndex];

        IList<string> lstStringTwo = new List<string>();
        lstStringTwo.Add("Kilometers:");
        lstStringTwo.Add("Miles:");
        lstStringTwo.Add("Meters:");
        lstStringTwo.Add("Feet:");
        lstStringTwo.Add("Centimeters:");
        lstStringTwo.Add("Inches:");
        label3.Text = lstStringTwo[cbConversion.SelectedIndex];

    }

    private void calculateConversions()
    {
        decimal input = Convert.ToDecimal(txtInput.Text);
        decimal mileToKM = Convert.ToDecimal(1.6093);
        decimal kMToMile = Convert.ToDecimal(0.6214);
        decimal ftToM = Convert.ToDecimal(0.3048);
        decimal mToFt = Convert.ToDecimal(3.2808);
        decimal inToCm = Convert.ToDecimal(2.54);
        decimal cmToIn = Convert.ToDecimal(0.3937);


        if (cbConversion.SelectedText.ToString() == "Miles to Kilometers")
        {
            decimal miles = (input * mileToKM);
            txtOutput.Text = miles.ToString();
        }
```

Comment: The problem is everytime you click the calculate button nothing happen? Are you calling the calculateConversions() function every time click the button?

Comment: yes, I even moved it to the click event and nothing happens.

Comment: Try to debug it make sure you hitting the calculateConversions() function.I updated my answered I post my whole code so you can check.